# How to evenly space table cells in Pages document?

Tags: pages

I would like to create a “grid” in a Pages document by creating a table whose cells are a certain size. Instead of manually dragging the walls of each cell, I would like to tell the program directly to, perhaps, divide the space into thirds, or to make each cell a specific measurement wide. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Pages you are able to enter the sizing/spacing for cells in a table in Pages. You are limited to entering specific measurements that is applied to all cells.

To do so go to the Tool Bar and select the Format Tab > Table Tab (have the table selected) then look to the bottom right corner of the window for where it says Row &  Column Size and it will let you enter the with Height and Width. I have included a screenshot as well to help.
[image: A step by step guide for changing the Row & Column sizes for a table in pages.]